# Scoring a very huge dataset

Tags: database, r, hadoop, bigdata, scoring

I have a fit a machine learning classifier on a sample data of 1-2% using R/Python and I'm pretty satisfied with the accuracy measures ( Precision,recall and F_score).

Now I would like to score a huge database with 70 Million rows/instances which resides in Hadoop/Hive environment with this classifier which is coded in R.

Information about the dataset:

70 Million X 40 variables( columns) : About 18 variables are categorical and the rest are 22 are numeric (integers included)

How do I go about doing it ? Any suggestions ?

The things I have thought of doing are:

a) Chunking the data out in 1 M increments out of the hadoop system in csv files and feeding it to R

b) Some kind of batch-processing.

Its not a real-time system, so doesn't need to happen everyday, but I would still like to score it in about 2-3 hours.

Answer (score 1):

If you can install R runtime on all your datanodes you can a simple [hadoop streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html#Hadoop+Streaming) map-only job that will invoke the R code

Also you can take a look at [SparkR](http://amplab-extras.github.io/SparkR-pkg/)

Answer (score 1):

I infer that you want to run your R code (your classifier) on a full dataset instead of sample datasets

So, we are looking for executing R code on a massively distributed system

Also, it must have a tight integration with hadoop components.

So RHadoop will fit in for your problem statement.

http://www.rdatamining.com/big-data/r-hadoop-setup-guide

Comment: The classifier is built using sample dataset -- i.e. only about 1% of the data. But I will look into RHadoop.

Answer (score 0):

```
The scoring of 80 million to 8.5 seconds

The code below was run on an off lease Dell T7400 workstation with 64gb ram, dual quad 3ghz XEONS and two raid 0 SSD arrays on separate channels which I purchased for $600. I also use the free SPDE to partition the dataset.

For small datasets like your 80 million you might want to consider SAS or WPS.
The code below scores  80 million 40 char records in 9 seconds

The combination of in memory R and SAS/WPS makes a great combinations. Many SAS users consider datasets less than 1TB to be small.

I ran 8 parallel processes, SAS 9.4 64bit Win Pro 64bit

8.5

%let pgm=utl_score_spde;

proc datasets library=spde;
delete gig23ful_spde;
run;quit;

libname spde spde 'd:/tmp'
  datapath=("f:/wrk/spde_f" "e:/wrk/spde_e" "g:/wrk/spde_g")
  partsize=4g;
;

data spde.littledata_spde (compress=char drop=idx);
  retain primary_key;
  array num[20] n1-n20;
  array chr[20] $4 c1-c20;
  do primary_key=1 to 80000000;
    do idx=31 to 50;
      num[idx-30]=uniform(-1);
      chr[idx-30]=repeat(byte(idx),40);
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;quit;



%let _s=%sysfunc(compbl(C:\Progra~1\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe -sysin c:\nul -nosplash -sasautos c:\oto -autoexec c:\oto\Tut_Oto.sas));

* score it;


data _null_;file "c:\oto\utl_scoreit.sas" lrecl=512;input;put _infile_;putlog _infile_;
cards4;
%macro utl_scoreit(beg=1,end=10000000);

  libname spde spde 'd:/tmp'
  datapath=("f:/wrk/spde_f" "e:/wrk/spde_e" "g:/wrk/spde_g")
  partsize=4g;

  libname out "G:/wrk";

  data keyscore;

     set spde.littledata_spde(firstobs=&beg obs=&end
        keep=
           primary_key
           n1
           n12
           n3
           n14
           n5
           n16
           n7
           n18
           n9
           n10
           c18
           c19
           c12);
    score= (.1*n1   +
            .1*n12  +
            .1*n3   +
            .1*n14  +
            .1*n5   +
            .1*n16  +
            .1*n7   +
            .1*n18  +
            .1*n9   +
            .1*n10  +
             (c18='0000')  +
             (c19='0000')  +
             (c12='0000'))/3  ;
    keep primary_key score;
  run;

%mend utl_scoreit;
;;;;
run;quit;

%utl_scoreit;


%let tym=%sysfunc(time());
systask kill sys101 sys102 sys103 sys104  sys105 sys106 sys107 sys108;
systask command "&_s -termstmt %nrstr(%utl_scoreit(beg=1,end=10000000);) -log G:\wrk\sys101.log" taskname=sys101;
systask command "&_s -termstmt %nrstr(%utl_scoreit(beg=10000001,end=20000000);) -log G:\wrk\sys102.log" taskname=sys102 ;
systask command "&_s -termstmt %nrstr(%utl_scoreit(beg=20000001,end=30000000);) -log G:\wrk\sys103.log" taskname=sys103 ;
systask command "&_s -termstmt %nrstr(%utl_scoreit(beg=30000001,end=40000000);) -log G:\wrk\sys104.log" taskname=sys104 ;
systask command "&_s -termstmt %nrstr(%utl_scoreit(beg=40000001,end=50000000);) -log G:\wrk\sys105.log" taskname=sys105 ;
systask command "&_s -termstmt %nrstr(%utl_scoreit(beg=50000001,end=60000000);) -log G:\wrk\sys106.log" taskname=sys106 ;
systask command "&_s -termstmt %nrstr(%utl_scoreit(beg=60000001,end=70000000);) -log G:\wrk\sys107.log" taskname=sys107 ;
systask command "&_s -termstmt %nrstr(%utl_scoreit(beg=70000001,end=80000000);) -log G:\wrk\sys108.log" taskname=sys108 ;
waitfor _all_ sys101 sys102 sys103 sys104  sys105 sys106 sys107 sys108;
systask list;
%put %sysevalf( %sysfunc(time()) - &tym);

8.56500005719863

NOTE: AUTOEXEC processing completed.

NOTE: Libref SPDE was successfully assigned as follows: 
      Engine:        SPDE 
      Physical Name: d:\tmp\
NOTE: Libref OUT was successfully assigned as follows: 
      Engine:        V9 
      Physical Name: G:\wrk

NOTE: There were 10000000 observations read from the data set SPDE.LITTLEDATA_SPDE.
NOTE: The data set WORK.KEYSCORE has 10000000 observations and 2 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           7.05 seconds
      cpu time            6.98 seconds



NOTE: SAS Institute Inc., SAS Campus Drive, Cary, NC USA 27513-2414
NOTE: The SAS System used:
      real time           8.34 seconds
      cpu time            7.36 seconds
```

Comment: I can use SAS, my co. is a big analytic shop, but how do I transfer the RandomForest or Naive-Bayes model  into the SAS ecosystem.